# Hide backup folder from dash quickstart

Tags: backup, unity-dash, directory

I have a nfs file share where I put all my files (NAS storage)
I also have a backup routine that copies the nfs file share to a local folder
When I now start a file using the dash the system finds both the nfs shared file and the on in backup folder, how to disable the backup folder?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new `Privacy` Settings in **System Settings** panel. Open it, Go to `Files` tab and add your backup folder in `Don't record activity in the following folder` list. Dash won't show the files inside that backup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the shared folder in dash; and select "Unlock from Launcher"